# array of data variables passed to a view , is passed to all views, is this a bug in codeigniter or i'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter

if i load 2 views like this in codeigniter in the same model :

```
$first = array('select' => 'anything');
$first = $this->load->view('first', $first, TRUE);
echo $first;
```

```
$second = array();
$second = $this->load->view('second', $second, TRUE);
echo $second;
```

Then the array of data ($first) passed to the first view is also available to the second view too.
like if i

```
echo $select;
```

variable in second view the value is echoed successfully which is the same as echoed in the first view, how can it be possible if i'm not passing any data to the second view? why it's getting the data passed to first view?
i'm using codeigniter 2.0, which is the latest version of codeigniter i think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do yo have 2 views inside a model? Views shouldn't be there. Also, could you show the whole method with which you load those views?

Comment: why not? views can be the part of the both model and controller, my method is just like normal, i'm loading views in model and then calling that model in my controller. thanks.

Comment: It's not a possibility problem, it is a work logic problem. That's the intent of separating logics, thus M-V-C. Not C(M+V). But it might be subjective, so I won't argue anymore

Comment: i transferred my views to my controller and then used my code then the result was same, but when i load them with the code mr. jondavidjohn told me, my problem get solved, but still there is a problem, i only want to load view by my code written above , 'cause i want to have views in the series i defined. thanks, and please help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because it is buffering the output and the view data is available globally to loaded views until the request is completed.

Which is actually AFTER the second view is output.

Have you tested this w/o using `echo` like this?

```
$first = array('select' => 'anything');
$this->load->view('first', $first);

$second = array();
$this->load->view('second', $second);
```

Do you get the same behavior?

*Not sure if it is a matter of incorrect language you're using, but you should be loading these views in the Controller, not the Model in keeping with the model the framework was built on, MVC*

**UPDATED TO ADD LINK ABOUT LOADING VIEWS SEQUENCIALLY**

http://www.askaboutphp.com/48/codeigniter-organizing-views-simply.html

Comment: i transferred my views to my controller and then used my code then the result was same, but when i load them with the code you told me my problem get solved, but still there is a problem, i only want to load view by my code written above , 'cause i want to have views in the series i defined. thanks, and please help further.

Comment: Well, since you're trying to bend the framework to be used in ways it wasn't intended, you're on your own there.

Comment: look sir, 
that the code you written above will be echoed too, but i will not be able to use those view in series which is most importent for me, and codeigniter doesn't say that "Hey! don't load view in series." why don't you understand?

Comment: After a quick google search I found the link I'll add to my answer to help you better understand how codeigniter intends you to accomplish this.